# What is a viable Hydra/Swarm Host/Viper build order?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg, sc2-build-order

My favorites units in hots is the swarm host, hydra, and viper together. I have a pretty decent overall strategy, but I don't have a good build order.

1. I tend to do a 13 pool and a early gas when the pool is finished.
2. Then I go for speedlings and early tech.
3. Before starting the Lair I get a second gas, and build hydra den and infestation pit soon as soon as I can support those units in economy.

What is a better build order for this?

Comment: identify how you like to play the early-midgame up to your dream comp, you'll need some good creep spread so a macro based 4 queen with some early roach ling map control build might be a good idea

Comment: I use speedlings to stop any early-midgame attacks along with early hydra to stop any air. I tend to have three base around the 20 minute mark. I have had games with this build order last over an hour with a slow but steady siege.

Comment: Here's a ZvP guide: http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Blade%27s_Guide_to_Zerg_vs._Protoss

Comment: I looked at that ZvP guide finally. Thank You for that, Decency. It helped me with some strategic thoughts about using the Swarm Host, but It doesn't answer my question about a good build oder.

Comment: First of, I think you should expand first, like a 15 hatch. But really only add the Viper if theres a need for it. I think you should aim on Hydra and Swarm Hosts first.

Comment: I tried a 15 hatch a couple times yesterday, but was punished for that multiple times. My opinion is using the minerals to get the hydra/swarm host combo sooner, and expand later.

Comment: @james.garriss You can do a pool first, then a Hatch. Your economu is so important for these units. Trust me, you will love having a strong economy on this build! Show me a few replays of your game if you like!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get an ultra-gas heavy composition like this, you're going to want to start with a macro build order like [Idra's 14 pool, 15 hatch](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/14_Pool_15_Hatch):

- 9 Overlord
- 14 Spawning Pool
- 15 Hatchery
- 16 Queen
- 18 Extractor
- 18 Overlord

No need for an early extractor, because this will get 4 extractors going quickly, and you've got a lot of teching time ahead of you.  As you transition, take an 3rd base just for gas.

Comment: I will try this out and then give you the bounty if it works out.

Answer (score 1):

The units that you mention are a very popular composition in a Zerg vs. Protoss match.
But can work against a Terran Mech player aswell. Though I would cut down on the Vipers versus a bio playing Terran.

One of the best fights I can think of, where these units gets the work done, is between Stephano and BabyKnight. Follow this link, and find game number 2!
[LINK](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7imVvn3-Zjo) This link will help you in terms of engagement and inspiration to the fight. Study what Stephano does.

Those units are very gas heavy. And you should focus on getting two gas on your bases relativly fast. Your focus should be on your economy and teching. But dont forget to constantly try to stress your opponant.

But what you need to do is:

- 15 Hatch and 3rd base at the 6 min mark.
- Get two gases on each base asap. Build your first two gases in your main base after you do your 15 Hatch.
- Build your tech as soon as you can - but remember to scout and act to
  what info you get.
- Always have one more base than your opponant.

To conclude on this, your economy is what you want to focus on, since this is very expensive. There are no direct build orders for this besides building your economy up. This is always the key to a strong Zerg army. As Zerg, you dont need 4 of the same tech production buildings - therfore economy is your friend in this!

Comment: I will try this out and then give you the bounty if it works out.

Comment: @jacen.garriss Sounds good. And remember that you can always add a pool before hatch if it makes you feel more secure! But the key here is your economy. Remember to get a macro hatch after you add on your 3rd base at 6 min. (macro hatch = extra hatch in your main)

Comment: @AtlasEU This doesn't seem like a very larva heavy build- why the macro hatch?

Comment: what is the optimal number of total drones to have when I have 3 bases and a macro hatch?

Comment: @jacen.garriss You should have 16 workers mining minerals and 3 on each gas on all bases. The macro hatch is only needed for unit production. You can place it in your main next to your mains hatch. This way its easier to inject larve!

Comment: @Decency The macro hatch is nice to have if you need to replenish workers, or need to finish off your opponent with mass zerglings. In general it helps you replenish your army faster - when and if you have a strong economy. Its only 300 minerals for so much more production. Its also a safe way to quickly make units if you main base is under siege. Having units running from your 3rd or 4th can be a pain as they get killed before reaching your main to help.